# Хостинг файлов

Tags: ftp, файлы, хостинг

Здравствуйте. Существуют ли хостинги файлов (не сайтов), с доступом по ftp на 2 подключения одновременно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В теории никто не мешает им существовать. На практике также. Вот взял первый попавшийся http://hosting.ua/ .
С какой целью ищем?

Comment: Дабы избежать исключений . Пробовал .narod , там нельзя.